# what header notification bar is being used here?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, notifications

http://codecanyon.net/item/foobar-a-jquery-notification-bar/241318?ref=hullabaloo_bard&clickthrough_id=36085359&redirect_back=true&ref=hullabaloo_bard

is it something that can be purchased (like a WP plug) or is it custom? i'd like to find one where i can adjust the appearance/logo like this. also, does anybody have any recommendations for a lightweight footer or header notification bar that's compatible with aweber?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be from a company called Envato: http://envato.com/

Possibly an affiliate program or something. I'm assuming it's custom and not a plugin.

When you inspect the HTML You see that the toolbar is "promo-strip", there appears to be an object managing the announcement and here is how it's being used:

```
 EnvatoAnnouncement.init('promo-strip', 'div.promo-strip h2', 'Close');
```

Judging by how the Object name is named after Envato, it would appear that it is custom and that they wrote it.

Comment: envato is simply the company that owns the site (and themeforest). if it's custom, is it jquery?

Comment: also, thanks! how were you able to tell it's custom and not a plugin?